# Return isn't working in my PHP function

Tags: php

I have created this select function with no escape to run simple queries where the data isn't coming from a user.

My function works and I can do what I intended with `global $var` however when I tried to return the value rather than make it a global variable it didn't work. I am just curious as to why this is.

Here is my function:

```
    function SelectQuery_NO_ESCAPE($row, $table, $row, $value) {
    $Database = DatabaseConnection();
    $sql_query = "SELECT $row FROM $table WHERE $row = '$value'";
    $select_result = $Database['Connection']->query($sql_query) or die(mysqli_error($Database['Connection']));
    if ($select_row = $select_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        global $select_row;
        $select_row = $select_row[$row];

    }
}
```

I have a `test.php` file where I use the function:

```
SelectQuery_NO_ESCAPE('ip', 'ip_address', 'ip', '1');
echo $select_row;
```

This works and outputs `1`. If I try to take out the global and just return the variable `$row_value` it doesn't work.

Why is this?

Comment: where is the return in the function? From what I see, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Do you really have two different `$row` arguments for your function?

Comment: Because you probably are doing nothing with the return value of the function. `echo SelectQuery...` would work.

Comment: @MarkBaker Oops my bad, I typed it out wrong, that wasn't meant to be like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return it:

```
if ($select_row = $select_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    return $select_row[$row];
}
```

Assign the returned value:

```
$something = SelectQuery_NO_ESCAPE('ip', 'ip_address', 'ip', '1');
echo $something;
//or
echo SelectQuery_NO_ESCAPE('ip', 'ip_address', 'ip', '1');
```

Comment: That's why, thank you. I will accept in 10 minutes when it allows me.